# Call function result from different activity on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I found a tutorial online for creating a QR Code Scanner App for Android. It works great but the output of the scan is a toast notification as you can see in the code:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.contents == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

What i would like to do is for the scanned code to launch the url inside the app itself. As I want the pages to be hosted in the app itself, what i've done was create an actvity with the webview that loads the internal html page.

I took the scanner code and changed the positive outcome to open the webview activity :
`startActivity(Intent(this, PagInfoActivity::class.java))`

Which works fine. Anytime a QR Code is detected the app automatically loads the desired activity. I know this is not ideal, as the QR Code link itself is not being used to open the page, but what I was trying to do was to use that scan result on the webview load. I've created QRCodes with text strings instead of URLs so that i could inject them in the loadURL of the webview like this:

```
WebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/*QRCODE string*.html");
```

Is it possible to call `result.contents` from the MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. First option can be `Explicit Intents`
For Example,
You need to pass it as an extra:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, PagInfoActivity.class);
i.putExtra("result", result.contents);
startActivity(i);
```

Then extract it from your PagInfoActivity like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String result= intent.getExtras().getString("result");
```

Comment: My pleasure, Happy coding :-)